# Could someone inform me How can i rate an order with a stars bas shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, rate

- Could someone inform me how can i rate an order items from a restaurant using a stars RateBar in flutter

Comment: Depends on your code and how rating is structured. Please share some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this dependency and integrate it in your code:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar